# How to escape a modifier symbol to remap the key in Autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to remap `"<"` key in Autohotkey. But `"<"` symbol is a modifier symbol. Therefore Autohotkey doesn't remap it like a normal key:

```
CapsLock & <::Send {`&}
```

How to escape a modifier symbol in order to remap that key?

Answer (score 2):

By default in AutoHotkey it is the grave accent/backtick character `

You can set it to be any other character in your script, if you prefer. Full details here: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_EscapeChar.htm

#### Edit:

Actually, I think you have something else going on here. `<` is not a modifier -- at least not in this context. I just tried this and it worked fine for me:

```
CAPSLOCK & <::Msgbox,it works!
```

Comment: :*:\pw::xZy8p`:`:13m   ;where the colons in the password are escaped

Answer (score 0):

I guess, using different keyboard layouts might cause compatibility problems.
so i suggest using SC56 (instead of <).

```
CapsLock & SC56::
```